# Error in if (k <= 0.8 && any(rr > (strwidth("W") * fsize/2))) rr <- rr/max(rr) *

Tags: r, tree, phylogeny

I am using the phytools package and I am trying to add the data for an extra trait to my phylogenetic tree by using the `dotTree` function but I get the error shown below.

I have tried to fix it by changing my data (trait) but others error appeared. Any suggestion?

```
trait<-as.matrix(read.csv("C:/Torres-Ruiz/JM/Proyectos-Experim/France/2018_Variation_P50/Analyses/Phylogeny/less spp/P50vsAllHmaxRAIN_Phylogeny2.csv",row.names=1))[,2]
trait
Rhododendron hirsutum Rhododendron x intermedium Senecio filaginoides Banksia sphaerocarpa
-3.230 -1.870 -5.000 -3.700
Mulinum spinosum Rhododendron ferrugineum Rosmarinus officinalis
-5.700 -3.010 -9.402
dotTree(myTree,trait)
Error in if (k <= 0.8 && any(rr > (strwidth("W") * fsize/2))) rr <- rr/max(rr) * :
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Answer (score 1):

Do the names of the traits and the tip labels match? The labels in the tree often contain underscores instead of white space.
E.g. `match(myTree$tip.label, names(trait))` should not contain any `NA`. Otherwise please provide a reproducible example.